# How to create field index using script in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm interested in creating field index using script.
Seen a function which creates field index with include root.
Didn't find a function which can create the field with path index.

Tried this function

```
admin:database-add-field-paths($config, $dbid, $field-name, $field-path)
```

Show "No field exist" in error.

Any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`admin:database-path-field`](http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-path-field). It's output can be added to the admin config using [`admin:database-add-field`](http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-add-field), roughly like follows:

```
let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $dbid := xdmp:database()
let $fieldspec := 
    let $field-name := "myField"
    let $field-paths := admin:database-field-path("/a/b", xs:double(2.0))
    return
        admin:database-path-field($field-name, $field-paths)

let $newConfig := admin:database-add-field($config, $dbid, $fieldspec)
```

It might also be worth taking a look at the Management REST api, which allows deploying configuration from outside, and with less programming. You'd need to send a PUT request to [`:8002/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties`](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties), with something like the following as part of the payload:

```
"field": [
    {
      "field-name": "status",
      "field-path": [
        {
          "path": "/pdbe:person-envelope/pdbm:person/pdbm:status",
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "path": "/pdbm:person/pdbm:status",
          "weight": 1
        }
      ],
      "field-value-searches": true
    }
]
```

HTH!